# Eclipse CDT crashes java

Tags: eclipse, crash

I downloaded fresh Eclipse CDT, added a C++ project, and after a few minutes eclipse crashed. It said "javaw.exe returned -1", and Eclipse crashes silently.

The `.metadata/.log` file sometimes contains nothing, and sometimes contains a few Java exception in the C/C++ indexer which certainly doesn't explain a silent crash.

How can I further debug this phenomena? I've no clue what to look for next.

I'm running the latest stable Eclipse CDT (7.0.1), with Windows 7 64bit, with the latest stable JDK (6u24).

Comment: YOu haven't told us what version of eclipse, what version of cdt, what version of Windows, or what version of java.

Comment: The question is general, how can I further debug it, are there any other log files, etc. I update the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On my machine, Windows 7, I have Eclipse in C:\Users\james\eclipse.  In that folder, after crashes, I see error files like "hs_err_pid4308.log" that have lots of useful information.

For my crashes, it lead me to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=333227 where I found a suggestion to add -XX:-UseCompressedOops to the end of my eclipse.ini file.  The ini file for my 64 bit Windows 7 non-crashing Eclipse Helios Service Release 2 Build id: 20110301-1815 with CDT now looks like:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:-UseCompressedOops
```

Comment: Thanks. I found that bug in the bug tracker eventually, but forgot to update here.