# Eclipse(CDT) crashes on Ctrl-clicking in Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, crash, eclipse-cdt

I am relatively new to Eclipse and I was trying to browse thru an existing C++ project I created. However every time I try & use ctrl-click on say a function invocation - instead of taking me to the declaration (or is it the definition?), Eclipse crashes.

I am running Eclipse 3.2 on 64-bit Ubuntu. I tried setting `-XX:-UseCompressedOops` in ~/.eclipse/eclipserc as was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054035/eclipse-cdt-crashes-java), but that resulted in:

```
/home/dp/.eclipse/eclipserc: line 1: -XX:-UseCompressedOops: command not found
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! TIA.

Note: Btw, I didn't find an eclipserc file in ~/.eclipse, so I just created a new one with just the one line in it(being `-XX:-UseCompressedOops`).

Comment: That answer you linked is talking about eclipse.ini, not .eclipserc.

Comment: Right. I (naively) assumed that I could either use the same option in eclipserc or pass it in via the commandline as `eclipse -XX:...`. However that didn't seem to help either.

Comment: No, no. In eclipse.ini, there is a specific --vmargs section. http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to eclipse.ini - I guess I was way off. :). Anyways, even after adding `-XX:-UseCompressedOops` to `/usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse.ini` it is still crashing. [This](http://pastebin.com/jMrba2Z4) is what I currently have in my eclipse.ini.

Comment: Sadly, I have no advice to offer about the crash *per se*.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Anyone else want to take a stab?

Comment: Get a newer jdk? Switch from OpenJDK to Snoracle?

Comment: I currently am using this: `$ java -version
    java version "1.6.0_18"
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.8.3) (6b18-1.8.3-0ubuntu1~8.04.2)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode)`

Any suggestions on which version I should be trying?

Comment: Try sun's java: sudo apt-get install sun-java6  (I think the package is still called sun...)

Comment: Tried java-1.6.0-openjdk and java-6-sun-1.6.0.24 (by setting `-vm` in eclipse.ini). Neither helped, it is still crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to Eclipse 3.7.0 and this problem was resolved. Thanks for the helpful suggestions, though.